# Delted apt.conf.d folder in /etc/apt how to download it

Tags: apt

i unfortunately deleted `apt.conf.d` folder in `/etc/apt` folder , now i am not able to download update any please provide me solution, i am using 13.10

can i copy it from my friends system using ubuntu 13.10 ,

or can i download any where else in web

when i created an empty folder as `apt.conf.d` it is giving me error

E: `Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:4: Extra junk at end of file`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! @user252888: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy it's contents from Ubuntu Installation CD or USB. Here is an example content of that folder:

```
karimov-danil@Karimov-Danil:~$ sudo ls /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
00aptitude        05aptitude      20auto-upgrades        70debconf
00trustcdrom          10periodic      20changelog        99synaptic
01autoremove          15update-stamp  20dbus             99update-notifier
01autoremove-kernels  20archive       50unattended-upgrades
```